# Remove all cordova platforms in one command

Tags: cordova

I have a cordova 8.1.2 project and really often I need to remove all the platforms already added and re-add them to solve exceptions.

There is a *simple* way to tell Cordova to remove all the platforms in one command?

I mean something like that :

```
cordova platform rm all
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's *NO COMMAND* you want now. For this, you can refer to this [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/platform/).

**Synopsis**:

```
$ ionic cordova platform [<action>] [<platform>]
```

According to the doc, there's no value of `all` for **platform** param but only **android** and **ios**.

> platform  The platform that you would like to add (**android**, **ios**)

Also, according to [Cordova doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/index.html#updating--removing-platforms), you can confirm that.

PS: For further discussion, you can join **Ionic Worldwide** slack channel and ask ionic stars like **Mike Hartington**.

Thanks for attention.